# send java array from jsp to controller in spring using ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, jsp

I have a jsp page which have a double[] array in java and a button, this is the code for JSP :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%

    double[] beta = {1.2,4.3,1.0};       

%>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    <button id="validate">Validate</button>


</body>
</html>
```

On validate button click I am making a ajax call which is sending request to controller :

```
$('#validate').click(function() {
$.ajax({
    url : 'controllerMethod'
    type : 'POST'
    data : ''
    success:function(data){

    }
});
});
```

How can I send beta array with ajax request so that i can access it in controller method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/controllerMethod", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
 public String validateSymbol(WebRequest webRequest,Model model,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    //beta;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Pass the array in your ajax data.
Here i make `data array`

```
$('#validate').click(function() {
  var data = [ "hello", "world" ];
$.ajax({
  url : 'controllerMethod',
  type: "POST", 
  dataType: 'json',
  data: "data="+data,
  success:function(data){

}
});
});
```

Get the String array i.e. `String[] data` using `@Requestparam` in controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/controllerMethod", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
 public String validateSymbol(WebRequest webRequest,Model model,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,@RequestParam String[] data) {

    //beta;
    //Here you will get your array in `data String array` which is passed from ajax call
 }
```

Comment: data array you created is in javascript, but my data array(beta) is in java, I think one way is to access java variable in javascript is `var data = <%=beta%>;` - but i am just looking for alternative bcs I am not sure it will going to preserve the data type of array which is double on moving from java to javascript to java.

Comment: @Naveen I think you will get array directly in jQuery so just pass it.